# Remove a set of tensors from a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking for an easy way to remove a set of tensors from a current tensor in Tensorflow and I'm having a difficult reasonable solution.

For example, let's say that I have the below current tensor:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```

And that I want to remove, say, two items from this tensor (2.0 and 5.0).

What would be the best way to transform this tensor into [1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0] after it has been created?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `tf.unstack` to obtain a list of sub-tensors. Then you can modify the list and call `tf.stack` to construct a tensor from the list. For example, the following code removes the [2.0, 5.0] column from a:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
a_vecs = tf.unstack(a, axis=1)
del a_vecs[1]
a_new = tf.stack(a_vecs, 1)
```

Comment: I'm not quite following, where are you specifying that you want to remove 2.0 and 5.0? How would this change if wanted to remove [1.0, 6.0], without hard coding it?

Comment: The shape of the tensor is (2, 3) then if you split the 6 values into two rows, the second values (with index=1) in each row will be 2 and 5 in the tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be either making use of split or slice function. This would be useful especially if tensor is huge.

**Method 1:** Making use of [split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) function.

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
split1, split2, split3 = tf.split(a, [1, 1, 1], 1)
a_new = tf.concat([split1, split3], 1)
```

**Method 2:** Making use of [slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) function.

```
slice1 = tf.slice(a, [0, 0], [2, 1])
slice2 = tf.slice(a, [0, 2], [2, 1])
a_new = tf.concat([slice1, slice2], 1)
```

In both the cases, a_new will have

```
[[ 1.  3.]
 [ 4.  6.]]
```