# elegant way to access python list and tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Python list, e.g. `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` can be accessed by `a[1]`. But I want to access values except index=1, that is, I want access `a[0]` and `a[3:]`. Is there a elegant way to access list (like `a[~1]`) could solve this?

In fact, I want to access tensor in tensorflow. I know several indexes I don't want to access, and I need all of others. Although we could solve this  in some tedious method, like redefine a variable link to other indexes, that  is not what we really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
# The index that you want to exclude
mask = tf.not_equal(tf.range(tf.shape(X)[0]), index)
masked = tf.boolean_mask(X, mask)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447183/remove-a-set-of-tensors-from-a-tensor-in-tensorflow there is also a solution. I think both are clear and easy to apply. Thanks to your reply, I will accept your answer.