# Remove from tensor randomly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to remove a row from a tensor randomly. The easiest way I saw so far is as follows (as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447183/remove-a-set-of-tensors-from-a-tensor-in-tensorflow)):

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
a_vecs = tf.unstack(a, axis=1)
val = tf.constant(1)
del a_vecs[val]
a_new = tf.stack(a_vecs, 1)
```

I want to pass to "del" a random integer that is based on a tensor operation. But when I use:

```
ran = tf.random_uniform((1,), minval=0, maxval=val, dtype=tf.int32)
```

I get back an array, and the del doesn't accept array. Also if there's an easier way to remove from the array let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.boolean_mask` of any size and shape you need. Create numpy array of bool values of desired shape with `np.random.choice`

```
#your_shape = int or array
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
ran = tf.random_uniform((1,), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
a_vecs = tf.unstack(a, axis=1)
rm = np.random.choice([True, False], your_shape)
a_new = tf.boolean_mask(a_vecs, rm)
```

Or you can  turn array to scalar with `np.asscalar`, but it will require running within a session.

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
ran = tf.random_uniform((1,), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
a_vecs = tf.unstack(a, axis=1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    r = ran.eval()
    val = np.asscalar(r)
    del a_vecs[val]
    a_new = tf.stack(a_vecs, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but your solution removes randomly, even more than one row. I just want to remove one row randomly. Also you solution assumes I know the desired shape in numpy, which I will need a tensor value for. However the Boolean mask might help, I will check it out